# Angular2 custom observables with some sequential subscribes

Tags: angular, promise, observable, sequential

do you know a solution for my problem?
I need a flexible sequence of subscribes capsuled in a observable like here:

```
saveData() {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      let success = true;

      if(example === true) {
        this.saveCallbarrings().subscribe((response) => {
          // this response was ignored from angular
          success = (response === true);
        });
      }

      if(example2 === true) {
        this.saveCallbarrings().subscribe((response) => {
          // this response was ignored from angular too
           success = (response === true);
        });
      }

      // and so on ... in the end I need a result of all responses
      observer.next(success);
    });
  }
```

In the end I called the result of this "response-collection" in my submit method:

```
onSubmit() {
// Validations and others
...
if(this.isNew) {
        observable = this.create();
      } else {
        observable = this.update();
      }

      return observable.subscribe(success => {
        if(success == true) {
          let subscription = this.saveData().subscribe(successFinished => {
            // And here is the problem, because this var doesnt have the correct response
            if(successFinished === true) {
              this.alertService.success('ALERT.success_saved', {value: 'ALERT.success_edit_user', param: {user: this.user.username}});
            }
          });

          subscription.unsubscribe();
        }
      });
```

The main problem is that angular doesn't waiting until the "success" var is subscribed in the the first code block. 
Why and what is the better solution for me?

Comment: You can't wait for an Observable or Promise to complete. You can only subscribe to it to get notified when it completes or emits an event. can you please add the saveExtendedData Service method as i feel u can make the change there ?

Comment: Sorry, I have a mistake in my second code block. The method  "this.saveExtendedData()" should be "this.saveData()".

Comment: in the save data method instead of assigning value to the success variable return the result

Comment: But I need the end result of all subscribes inside the observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st question: Why is it not working?

Because every subscribe is asynchronous. When you do `this.saveCallbarrings().subscribe(...)` the thing inside subscribe can happen at any time (maybe never!), so the program continues to the next instruction, that's `observer.next(success);`, that has the initial value of `success`.

2nd question: What is the best solution for me?

Rx.Observables have [so many operators](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html) to deal with this asynchronous stuff. In your case, the operator you need is [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html). This operator lets you pass him an array of streams, and it will subscribe to all of them and when all of them finish it will give you an array with each one of the resuts for each stream. So your code would become:

```
saveData() {
    return Rx.Observable.defer(() => {
        let streams = [];
        if(example === true) {
            streams.push(this.saveCallbarrings());
        }
        if(example2 === true) {
            streams.push(this.saveCallbarrings());
        }

        // And so on

        return Rx.Observable.forkJoin(streams);
    });
}
```

Having said that, I'm not sure why you make many subscriptions to the same `this.saveCallbarrings()`, I guess it's just to make the question simpler, as an example.

Also, here I used `.defer()` instead of create. With this you can just return another stream and it will subscribe to it and pass it to the observers. The difference between doing `defer` and doing nothing (i.e. setting up the streams and just returning the forkJoin) is that `defer` won't execute any of the code until someone subscribes to it, so you get less side effects.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution works for me successfully!